# VisibleDeprecationWarning when stacking lists with numpy and how to export in Excel with a given configuration

Tags: python, excel, numpy

I'm having two problems, first this line:

```
merged_lists = np.column_stack([nouns, lemmas, poses, xposes, heads, deprels])
```

Returns me this traceback:

> VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
> arr = asanyarray(v)

And when I add dtype=object it returns me this other error and stops the program:

> merged_lists = np.column_stack([nouns, lemmas, poses, xposes, heads, deprels], dtype=object)
> File "<**array_function** internals>", line 179, in column_stack
> TypeError: _column_stack_dispatcher() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

I already fixed it but apparently I forgot to save or something and now I can't remember how I did it, but I wasn't specifying dtype=object

Here's the whole code for context:

```
import stanza
import numpy as np
import time
import re
import csv


def line_count(file_name):  # counts the number of lines of the file
    file = open(file_name, 'rb')
    lines = 0
    buf_size = 1024 * 1024
    read_f = file.read

    buf = read_f(buf_size)
    while buf:
        lines += buf.count(b'\n')
        buf = read_f(buf_size)

    return lines


def remove_emoji(string):
    emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
                               u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
                               u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
                               u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
                               u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                               u"\U00002500-\U00002BEF"  # chinese char
                               u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
                               u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
                               u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
                               u"\U0001f926-\U0001f937"
                               u"\U00010000-\U0010ffff"
                               u"\u2640-\u2642"
                               u"\u2600-\u2B55"
                               u"\u200d"
                               u"\u23cf"
                               u"\u23e9"
                               u"\u231a"
                               u"\ufe0f"  # dingbats
                               u"\u3030"
                               "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    return emoji_pattern.sub(r'', string)


def create_filtered_text(string):
    x = open(string, encoding='utf-8')
    text = x.read().replace('eos', '\n').replace('0', ' ').replace('1', ' ').replace('2', ' ').replace('3', ' ') \
        .replace('4', ' ').replace('5', ' ').replace('6', ' ').replace('7', ' ').replace('8', ' ').replace('9', ' ') \
        .replace(',', ' ').replace('"', ' ').replace('·', ' ').replace('?', ' ').replace('¿', ' ').replace(':', ' ') \
        .replace(';', ' ').replace('-', ' ').replace('!', ' ').replace('¡', ' ').replace('.', ' ').replace(' \n', '') \
        .replace('ℹ', ' ').replace('    ', ' ')
    text = remove_emoji(text)
    x.close()

    # we replace all the numbers and most of the symbols with spaces, .replace(' \n', '') is most important as it
    # deletes all the empty lines which are left after .replace('.', ' ')

    x = open("FILTERED_" + string, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    x.write(text)
    x.close()


def create_merged_list(string, language):
    string = "FILTERED_" + string
    errors = 0  # IndexError counter
    stanza.download(language)  # no need to check if it's downloaded every time, only the first time
    nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang=language)  # setting the pipeline, 'ca' for catalan

    nouns = []
    lemmas = []
    poses = []
    xposes = []
    heads = []
    deprels = []

    # total_lines = line_count(string)  # saving the number of lines of the file

    i = 0  # counts iterations, not needed now
    rn = 50  # number of lines to process

    # range should be total_lines which is 6682 in this case, takes a long time though. I got to 3k+ once, the error
    # counter started to go up at about 1200, then it stopped at 3k aprox due to IndexError           #Fixed
    x = open(string, encoding='utf-8')
    text = x.read().splitlines()
    for line in range(rn):
        i = i + 1
        noun = ["NOUNS"]
        lemma = ["LEMMAS"]
        pos = ["POS"]
        xpos = ["XPOS"]
        head = ["HEAD"]
        deprel = ["DEPREL"]
        doc = nlp(text[line])

        try:  # no need for these two try/expect, but let's leave it anyway for tests
            for word in doc.sentences[0].words:
                noun.append(word.text)
                lemma.append(word.lemma)
                pos.append(word.pos)
                xpos.append(word.xpos)
                deprel.append(word.deprel)

        except IndexError:
            print("2nd" + str(i))
            errors += 1
            pass

        try:
            for word in doc.sentences[0].words:
                head.extend([lemma[word.head - 1] if word.head > 0 and lemma[word.head - 1] != "LEMMAS" else "root"])
                # error, HEADS row getting filled with 'LEMMAS'         # Fixed

        except IndexError:
            pass

        nouns.append(noun)
        lemmas.append(lemma)
        poses.append(pos)
        xposes.append(xpos)
        heads.append(head)
        deprels.append(deprel)
    x.close()
    # column stack seems most useful and more visual although others are good too
    merged_lists = np.column_stack([nouns, lemmas, poses, xposes, heads, deprels])
    # returns VisibleDeprecationWarning even though all arrays are the same size         # Fixed
    
    print("errors: " + str(errors))  # weird, seems to be range/2-1         # Fixed
    return merged_lists


def to_csv(string, name):
    with open("CSV_" + str(name[:-4]) + ".csv", 'w', newline='') as c:
        writer = csv.writer(c, delimiter=',')
        for i in range(len(string)):
            for j in range(len(string[0])):
                writer.writerow(string[i][j])
            c.write("\n")


filename = input("Enter the name (with format) of the text you want to filter\n")
lang = input("In what language is the text typed? ('ca' for catalan, 'es' for spanish, 'en' for english...\n")
start = time.time()
create_filtered_text(filename)
merged = create_merged_list(filename, lang)
to_csv(merged, filename)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

I also have another issue, when I create the csv file and open it with excel it appears like this:

[image: Not pretty]

But when I open excel and import the data from the same csv it appears like this:
[image: Pretty!]

Which is how I want it to look like, how could I modify my 'to_csv' function so it does that?

And, as a side note, I have tried to use this instead of all the replaces:

```
text = re.sub(r'[\d,"·?¿:;!¡.-]', ' ', text)
```

But it doesn't work, the filtered text is different and somehow makes it so after .splitlines() my  'remove_emoji' function stops working, anybody knows how to exactly replace the replaces with re.sub so it does exactly the same?

Many thanks!

Comment: `column_stack` converts all the input objects to numpy array.  It's in the process of doing `asarray` on one of `nouns, lemmas, poses, xposes, heads, deprels` that the warning is raised.  Try `np.array(nouns)`, etc on each of those inputs.  One or more is a list that contains lists or arrays that vary in size.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the answer, the contents can be seen in both images, aren't those numpy arrays?

Comment: @hpaulj I did np.array() on each of them and they all gave me visible deprecating warning.
But when I calculate the dimensions, they all match: https://imgur.com/a/uhygQ8t

Comment: and did you examine the resulting arrays?  I guess they are all 1d object dtype arrays.

Comment: This is just a warning, not an error.  Using `np.array(yourlist, dtype=object)` silences the warning, but the resulting array is the same.  `column_stack` will combine those (n,) shape arrays into a (m,n) shape, still object dtype.  Whether that's useful array, or makes a nice `csv` is another matter.  Without knowing the source of that 'raggedness' I can't help.  It might help if you showed part of the csv text file (without excel's interpretation).  Remember as nice csv is a 2d table - rows with a consistent number of columns, each 'cell' being a simple number or string.

Comment: In the desired spreedsheet, some rows have 3 columns, some 11, and some more.  That's  "ragged".  In the 'actual', it appears that each line is just one string, the same values as in the desired, but joined into one comma separated string.  Again, I can't really diagnose the excel, the actual csv text might tell me more.  You might want to start with a simpler case, one where you can actually examine each step, rather than depend one loading the excel file at the end.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure using `numpy` helps you here.  The collection process is all lists.  And the csv writing is basically list oriented as well.  Doing that `column_stack` adds an unnecessary array layer.

Comment: @hpaulj these are the contents of the csv: https://imgur.com/a/5QXrERN
How could I do it without numpy? I want to add the lists onto a 2d array, also column_stack leaves it with the format I want.

Comment: list(zip(a,b,c))` is a list transpose

Comment: @hpaulj doesn't work, gives a bunch of other errors, I'm just gonna use this:
np.warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=np.VisibleDeprecationWarning)
and ignore the errors

Answer (score 0):

Your question was about the ragged warning, though it appears (from the comments) that the real issue was how you loaded the csv in excel.  I did ask you to look at/show the actual csv rather than the excel image.

But here's what I was suggesting regarding using lists instead of array.

Let's make a dummy set of lists:

```
In [105]: nouns = []; lemmas = []; poss = []
     ...: for i in range(3):
     ...:     noun = ['NOUNS']; lemma=['LEMMAS']; pos=['POS']
     ...:     noun.extend(['Foo']*(i+2))
     ...:     lemma.extend(['bar']*(i+2))
     ...:     pos.extend(['xxx']*(i+2))
     ...:     nouns.append(noun); lemmas.append(lemma);poss.append(pos)

In [106]: (nouns,lemmas,poss)
Out[106]: 
([['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo'],
  ['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo'],
  ['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo']],
 [['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar'],
  ['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
  ['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']],
 [['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx'],
  ['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'],
  ['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx']])
```

Your use of `column_stack`:

```
In [107]: np.column_stack((nouns,lemmas,poss))
C:\Users\paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py:652: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  arr = asanyarray(v)
Out[107]: 
array([[list(['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo']), list(['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar']),
        list(['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx'])],
       [list(['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo']),
        list(['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']),
        list(['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'])],
       [list(['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo']),
        list(['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']),
        list(['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'])]], dtype=object)
```

This looks a lot like the transpose of the original tuple of lists:

```
In [108]: _.T
Out[108]: 
array([[list(['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo']),
        list(['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo']),
        list(['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo'])],
       [list(['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar']),
        list(['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']),
        list(['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'])],
       [list(['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx']), list(['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx']),
        list(['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'])]], dtype=object)
```

A well known idiom for "transposing" a list of lists:

```
In [109]: zz = list(zip(nouns, lemmas, poss))

In [110]: zz
Out[110]: 
[(['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo'], ['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar'], ['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx']),
 (['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo'],
  ['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
  ['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx']),
 (['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo'],
  ['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
  ['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'])]
```

This groups the sublists in the same as `column_stack`.  In fact if we turn that array into a list, we get the same thing (here tuples and lists are equivalent):

```
In [111]: Out[107].tolist()
Out[111]: 
[[['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo'], ['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar'], ['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx']],
 [['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo'],
  ['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
  ['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx']],
 [['NOUNS', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'Foo'],
  ['LEMMAS', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
  ['POS', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx']]]
```

Your csv write should work the same.